# Laravel eloquent query issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get all users with images relation one to many. Where in images table column type is equal to 1.

Closest I created.

```
  User::with('Images')->has('Images')->get();
```

but it return all images not only with type 1;

Also I tried

```
$a = User::defaultImage()->get();
```

and in user model def scope

```
   public function scopeDefaultImage($query) {

            $query->whereHas('Images', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('default', 1);
                })->get();






        return $query;
    }
```

but it doesn't return relation with images, only user

Comment: How's your relationship defined?

Comment: om my user model i have  public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to modify the way you are using your `with` function.  This would make it so that the only images returned would be of type 1.

```
User::with(['Images' => function($q) {
    $q->where('type', 1);
}])->whereHas('Images', function($q) {
    $q->where('type', 1);
})->get();
```

By also adding the `whereHas`, this will return only the users that have an image type of 1 attached.

I also would make sure in your database that you do have users and they are attached to images with image type of 1 so that you know for sure you should be getting some data back.

Adding additional constraints, you just chain on another `whereHas`

```
User::with(['Images' => function($q) {
    $q->where('type', 1);
}])->whereHas('Images', function($q) {
    $q->where('type', 1);
})->whereHas('Roles', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', 5);
})->get();
```

Comment: tnx sir work great i will vote up and set as correct but pls could add one more clause, i have also table Roles with entrust api so i have pivot table. I just want one more clause where Role = 5. I am new to laravel pls help